# package.json returns ERROR: Invalid version if use custom version

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, semantic-versioning

```
ERROR: Invalid version: "1.2.1.3.2022"
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Is there a way to disable check for semantic versioning?
Changing version format to X.Y.Z is not an option since having X.Y.Z.A.BBBB is a strict requirement.

Comment: Do you have to publish the package? Otherwise the version is optional and you can use another field to store your custom version. The version field must be parseable by node-semver.

Comment: No, it`s a private repository. I have no issues with the build, but starting dev server I always get the error. Is there a property to skip parsing?

Comment: Why do you use the field `version`? Use your own field `custom_version`. The field `version` is optional, but when you set it, it has to be parseable by node-semver.